# Disable/remove Kendo mvc validator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, grid, kendo-ui

A simple question, or so I thought.
How to disable client side validation for kendo mvc grid?
I thought there would be a property: "Enabled", "validator" or such which I could set to false but I can't find nothing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're correct in that there's no way to disable the validation via a property or options setting, however, you can work around it.

The validators for the grid cells are created internally by the grid. You can disable validation by replacing the functions of the validator object in the "edit" event of the grid, after it is created, i.e.:

```
edit: function (e) {
    // Always return valid
    e.sender.editable.validatable.validate = function () { return true; };
    e.sender.editable.validatable.validateInput = function(input) { return true; };
}
```

This should have the effect of disabling validation by always returning true.

EDIT:

You might also want to replace validateInput, I've updated the code snippet.

Comment: This is what I did:
In the grid:
    `.Events(ev => ev
        .Edit("edit")
    )`
In script:
    `function edit(e) {
        e.sender.editable.validatable.validate = function () { return true; };
    }`

But it still validates.

Comment: It worked for me in my code sample, but you may also need to replace the validateInput method. See the edit above.